# Add pagination to custom products output in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, pagination, shortcode, product

I have a function below that outputs products to the single_product_page. I want to be able to add pagination to this.

brand_products belongs to a plugin (woocommerce brands - offical wooplugin from woocommerce).
All running the latest versions.

What my ultimate goal is {

On the single_product_page just above the tabs is to list products from the Taxonomy Brand (Woocommerce Brand). Brand Products holds the products with a particular brand name. I wish to output this 3 at a time with pagination.

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'custom_woocommerce_output_brand_products', 10 );
function custom_woocommerce_output_brand_products(){
    global $product;
    $pid = $product->get_id();
    $brands = wp_get_post_terms($pid, 'product_brand');
    foreach($brands as $brand){
        $brand_name = $brand->name; break;
    }
    echo do_shortcode('[brand_products brand="'.$brand_name.'" per_page="3" columns="3"]');
}
```

How can I add pagination to this displayed products?

Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: where is the code for this custom shortcode `[brand_products]` or may be you are using a plugin and you should mention it with the versions of Woocommerce and Wordpress that you are using.

Comment: thanks I have added hat info plus what my ultimate goal is. Maybe I am doing it a round about  way :)